# Efficiently convert a long string to long in Java

Tags: java, types, type-conversion

I've really a long sequence of characters such as 123222222222230000000000001. I want to convert this to a long. What is the most efficient way to do it in Java?

UPDATE: The max length of sequence is of 31 characters

Comment: were are talking decimal here, right? not octal.

Comment: as noted there is no direct way to fit a 31 digit decimal number into a long. Somehow it need to be convert (use only the least/most significant digits, use 2 longs, or ...). A hint about what that number will be used for would be helpfull.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, a string value like that will never fit into a `long` (it is much to large),

You will need to use the [`BigInteger`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) type and the [constructor that accepts a `String` parameter](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(java.lang.String)):

> Translates the decimal String
>   representation of a BigInteger into a
>   BigInteger. The String representation
>   consists of an optional minus sign
>   followed by a sequence of one or more
>   decimal digits. The character-to-digit
>   mapping is provided by
>   Character.digit. ***The String may not
>   contain any extraneous characters
>   (whitespace, for example).***

Comment: true. The example string is "too long".

Comment: sorry for making it too long than required, the max length will be of 31 characters that I need to convert

Comment: Given the fact Long.MAX_VALUE = 2^63 - 1, which has 19 digits in it, there's still no chance it'll fit in a long. Use BigInteger as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot fit 31 digits into a long, but just for reference:

```
 long primitive = Long.parseLong(longString); 
 Long object = Long.valueOf(longString);
```

Comment: the first line throws an error. so I'm pretty much sure this doesn't work

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException

Comment: that is because your number is "too long". You need to use a BigInteger.

Answer (score 1):

```
BigDecimal
```

can also be used to convert string to long.

Comment: but not the 31-digit strings he has in mind. Those are just too long for long.